# user_data not getting executed over instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, terraform

I have provided an `.sh` file as `user_data` in my Terraform script:

```
resource "aws_instance" "alpha-terraform"{
    ami=var.amis[var.region]
    instance_type="t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids=[aws_security_group.alpha-terraform-sg.id]
    user_data = file("user_data_bootstrap.sh")
    key_name = "alpha-terraform"

    tags={
        type="alpha"
        purpose="terraform"        
    }
}
```

The `.sh` file contains:

```
#Jenkins Installation:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk --yes
wget –q –O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add –
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install Jenkins
sudo systemctl status jenkins
find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8* | head -n 3
```

My instance is getting created all right. However, I believe my user_data is not getting executed. I can see the user_data is being copied to `/var/lib/cloud/instance/` as `user-data.txt` and `user-data.txt.i` but still not getting executed.

Why is this happening and how can I debug it further?

### Update

I tried accessing the server through and executing each command one by one but getting following error while updating apt packages:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-52-**:~$ apt update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-52-**:~$ sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: Which ubuntu version? Also you can check on the instance `/var/log/cloud-init-ouput.log`

Comment: @Marcin `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial)`. Nothing unusual in logs except for device, route and key info and below at the end:

`WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80`

Comment: That warning message is printed by `apt` itself, so its presence confirms that your script _is_ being executed, but that it isn't succeeding to do what you intended. When you tried to reproduce the script from the command line you ran it as user `ubuntu`, which has different access than `cloud-init` does; for a more realistic reproduction, use `sudo apt update` to run `apt` with superuser permissions.

Comment: With that said, my guess is that the network configuration for your instance is blocking it from reaching over the internet to the Ubuntu package repositories. You could confirm this by trying to reach other `http` and `https` addresses using a command like `curl`. If no host on the internet is accessible, I'd suggest starting a new question about configuring outbound internet access for an EC2 instance, and include in that question the configuration for your VPC(s), subnet(s), and security group(s) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **verified** the script on my sandbox account.

It had **mistakes**. The corrected version is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

#Jenkins Installation:
apt update
apt install openjdk-8-jdk --yes
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt install -y jenkins
systemctl status jenkins
find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8* | head -n 3
```

The **changes** were:

- removal of `sudo`
- fixing `–` to `-`
- fixing `apt install Jenkins` to `apt install -y jenkins`

I can **confirm that it works** now with `terraform` on Ubuntu 18.04 instance.

Upon launching the instance, `jenkins` is available at `http://<instance-ip>:8080`:

[image]

Comment: I tried exact script you have given above but still its not working. Anywhere i can debug it or find tracelogs?

Comment: @Maven What exactly OS are you using. The script provided works on Ubuntu 18.04. I tested it as explained in the answer on the OS. Nevertheless you can inspect `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) over [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) where you have more control and pass variable to user data as well.

> `templatefile` reads the file at the given path and renders its content as a template using a supplied set of template variables where `file` reads the contents of a file at the given path and returns them as a string.

```
templatefile(path, vars)
```

```
data "template_file" "backend_cloud_init" {
  template = "${file("user_data_bootstrap.sh")}"
  vars = {
    JDK_VERSION = "openjdk-8-jdk"
  }
}
```

then use the template_file in a userdata section

```
resource "aws_instance" "alpha-terraform"{
    ami=var.amis[var.region]
    instance_type="t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids=[aws_security_group.alpha-terraform-sg.id]
    user_data                   = "${data.template_file.backend_cloud_init.rendered}"
    key_name = "alpha-terraform"

    tags={
        type="alpha"
        purpose="terraform"        
    }
}
```

Also, add the hashbang in the file with debug

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

> User data shell scripts must start with the `#!` characters and the path to the interpreter you want to read the script (commonly /bin/bash). For a great introduction on shell scripting, see the [BASH Programming HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) at the Linux Documentation Project ([tldp.org](http://tldp.org/)).

Comment: Done but still not working, anywhere i can debug it or find tracelogs for user data execution?

Comment: Same documentation lists a few gotchas and suggests looking in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Answer (score 0):

To help troubleshooting, it's a good idea to SSH and check folder `/var/lib/cloud/instances/instance-id/`. You should find the data_user script there. Read it to check if everything is as expected.